# Wordpress Hook for user account activation

Tags: wordpress

what is the action hook, if a user activates his profile? For the profile update, it is:

```
profile_update
```

for example.

Comment: I am working on a gamification plugin for Wordpress and was looking for the same thing when I found this article. Didn't test it yet but I hope it works. [article link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15683/wordpress-hook-for-user-account-activation-in-normal-wp-not-mu)

Answer (score 5):

Old question which may not have been fully answered: the user may be using BuddyPress which may require an activation step after the initial user registration, even on single sites.

In that case, the `user_register` action happens immediately after an account is registered, but before it is activated. After the user is activated, the `bp_core_activated_user` action happens.

http://hookr.io/actions/bp_core_activated_user/

Comment: While this is specific to using BuddyPress, this answered my question (and I am using BuddyPress...). +1 to you sir

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe late but i like point that `personal_options_update` would solve your problem.

use can use some hooks on this like:

```
    action('personal_options_update', 'update_pass_meta');
    // update user meta during profile update
    function profilescreen($user, $pass1, $pass2){
        $currnt_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $userid = $currnt_user->ID;
        update_user_meta($userid, '_temp_user_pass', $pass2 );
    }

    function update_pass_meta() {
        add_action( 'check_passwords','profilescreen', 10, 3);
    }
```

Regards,

Answer (score -1):

This might be what you are looking for: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register

For multisite Wordpress I have also used the 'wpmu_activate_user' action.

Comment: Nope not really. If a user is registers, I need user_register. But if he is registered, he is not activated, yet. First when he clicks the Link in the activation mal, he is activated. Right on this point, my plugin shall do something....not earlier and not later

Comment: Nope not really. They *are* activated when user_register fires. If you go to the link that I gave you you will see that this happens "immediately after they are added to the database". Users are not in the wp_users table before they are activated and they don't have a user_id. Unactivated signups are in the wp_signups table.

Comment: Nope. Thats wrong. User get added to wp users directly after signup. There is not table wp_signups. They also get a user ID directly after the signup. I just did a test.

Comment: What I am describing is the multisite case. In the single site case, as far as I know, there isn't an activation step. The user just gets email with their password. So then I'm not sure what you mean by "activate" in this context.

Comment: Yep, I am talking about the single site. What I mean by activate: You have some user hooks like: user_register or profile_update. I am looking for the hook, for the user activation, to execute my function. Like: add_action( 'user_activate','my_function');

Comment: I'm really not trying to be difficult here, but I still don't think I understand what you mean by activate. To my mind a user is activated as soon as they register in the single site case because their entry is created in the user table immediately and they get sent a password in email. There is no 'activation' per se. Maybe it would help if you explain what "my_function"will do.